# Check if a specific key exists in firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[data in my firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOSJ4.png)

I have this data in my firebase realtime database , but I have a struggle in checking if a specific identification number (say 1122334455) exists under "Identification number" or Not.

below is my code and it doesn't work as expected

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PutOf.png)

Comment: can you paste the code here rather than giving the image..

Comment: You've included links to pictures of the code and the JSON tree in your question. Please replace these with the actual code and JSON as text, the latter of which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and code and use them in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to check if a **key** exists, you'll want to use `orderByKey()`.

So:

```
var ref = firebase.database()
                  .reference("Identification number")
                  .orderByKey().equalTo(form.userid.value)...
```